# How to install informatica 10.1.0 on windows 10 Pro 64-bit?

Tags: windows, informatica

How to install informatica 10.1.0 on windows 10 Pro 64 bit?

I have downloaded files from https://edelivery.oracle.com/. Extracted files and double clicked on install.bat file. But only a black screen flashes for a second.

Informatica 10.1 Files

[image: Informatica 10.1 Files]

System Details:

Operating system: **Windows 10 Pro 64-bit**
RAM: 16 GB

Java version: Java 7 64-bit (Also tried with Java 8)

**Is there any other prerequisite for informatica 10.1.0? 
Is it compatible with Windows 10 Pro 64-bit?**

Please give me any solution or suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Informatica server does not support on windows 10 pro.

Comment: Do you have a source to back this up?